# JSF DataTable command buttons not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces, managed-bean

I am using primefaces 3.3, have 3 components on page: data table, edit area, command button. I have 1 strange issue: when I open page, data is displayed in data table, but if I click on any of button, debugger suggests that corresponding button code is not even called. However, if I click on any record in table, edit area is populated, then if I click on buttons they start working.
below is page code, i tried different options, putting all content in 1 form etc., none works. please help

```
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="form" prependId="false">
            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>  
            <p:dataTable id="table" var="var" 
                         value="#{regions.list}" 
                         selection="#{regions.selected}"  
                         rowKey="#{var.idRegion}"
                         selectionMode="single" 
                         paginator="true" rows="10" 
                         paginatorPosition="bottom"                                  
                         >                                
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{regions.onRowSelect}" update=":frmEdit :form:growl"  />  
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{regions.onRowUnSelect}"  update=":frmEdit :form:growl"/>  

                <f:facet name="header">  
                    List of Regions  
                </f:facet>  
                <p:column sortBy ="#{var.shortName}">
                    <f:facet name="header">Short Name</f:facet> 
                    <h:outputText value="#{var.shortName}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column sortBy ="#{var.fullName}">
                    <f:facet name="header">Full Name</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{var.fullName}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column sortBy ="#{var.created}">
                    <f:facet name="header">Created On</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{var.created}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
                            </h:form>
            <p:panel header="Add/Edit Properties">
        <h:form id="frmEdit">
                <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="6" cellpadding="4" >

                    <h:outputText value="Short Name:" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{regions.selected.shortName}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Full Name:" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{regions.selected.fullName}" />

                </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
        <h:form id="frmBtn">
                <h:panelGrid id="command" columns="6"  cellpadding="4" >
                    <p:commandButton id="new" value="New" actionListener="#{regions.add()}"  process="@this :frmEdit"  update="result :frmEdit :form" >                                
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton id="save" value="Save" actionListener="#{regions.save()}" process="@this :frmEdit"  update="result :frmEdit :form" >                                
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton id="delete"  value="Delete" actionListener="#{regions.delete()}"  process="@this :frmEdit"  update="result :frmEdit :form" >                                
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton id="refresh"  value="Refresh" actionListener="#{regions.refresh()}"  process="@this :frmEdit"  update="result :frmEdit :form" >                                
                    </p:commandButton>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <p:messages id="result" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>  
        </h:form>
            </p:panel>
    </ui:define>
```

below is JSF MB Code:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Regions implements Serializable {
    private List<Region> list;
    private Region selected;
    private @EJB RegionFacade esvc;  //entity services    
    private FacesContext context;
    private FacesMessage msg;
    private boolean newRec =false;

    @SuppressWarnings("OverridableMethodCallInConstructor")
    public Regions() {
//        context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
//        HttpSession session = (HttpSession)context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
//        Users user = (Users)session.getAttribute("user");
//        if (user != null)
//            init();
//        else {
//            msg = new FacesMessage("Session Expired, Return to Login Page");
//            context.addMessage(null, msg);
//        }
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){        
        try{
            list = esvc.findAll();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public String add(){
        selected = new Region();          
        newRec = true;
        return "region";
    }

    public String save(){
        int result;
        if (newRec){
            result=esvc.insert(selected);
            newRec=false;
        }
        else{       
            result=esvc.update(selected);
        }
        refresh();
        context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if (result>0){
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Success", "Record Saved");
            refresh();
        }else{
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Failure", "Record not Saved");            
        }
        context.addMessage(null, msg);
        return "region";
    }

    public String delete(){
        int result;
        result= esvc.delete(selected);
        context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        refresh();
        if (result>0){
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Success", "Record Deleted");            
            refresh();
        }else {
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Failure", "Record not Deleted");            
        }
        context.addMessage(null, msg);
        return "region";
    }

    public void refresh(){
        selected=null;
        list=getList();         
    }

    public List<Region> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public Region getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(Region selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        msg = new FacesMessage("Selected", ((Region) event.getObject()).getFullName());
        context.addMessage(null, msg);
    }


    public void onRowUnSelect(UnselectEvent event) {
        context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        selected=null;
    }    

}
```

Comment: Why do you have a separate form for you buttons?

Answer (score 0):

An `ActionListener` method (to be used on the `actionListener` attribute like you have) must take an `ActionEvent` parameter and of `void` return type. Remove the `actionListener` attribute on your command button and use the `action` attribute if you want to keep your method signature. If however you need to process the event immediately the event is fired on the button, you must change your method signature to fulfil the `ActionListener` [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html).